# Postgresql Constraint on row value based on other rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, check-constraints, exclude-constraint

Given the following schema

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    value text,
    flag bool
);
```

is this possible, to create such constraint which would allow duplicate rows with the same `value` and `flag = true`, but would allow at most once row with the given `value` and `flag = false`

e.g.

These should execute without errors

```
INSERT INTO test (value, flag) VALUES ('1', true);
INSERT INTO test (value, flag) VALUES ('1', true);
INSERT INTO test (value, flag) VALUES ('1', true);
INSERT INTO test (value, flag) VALUES ('1', true);
```

```
INSERT INTO test (value, flag) VALUES ('1', true);
INSERT INTO test (value, flag) VALUES ('1', true);
INSERT INTO test (value, flag) VALUES ('1', false);
```

```
INSERT INTO test (value, flag) VALUES ('1', false);
INSERT INTO test (value, flag) VALUES ('1', true);
```

And this should raise an error

```
INSERT INTO test (value, flag) VALUES ('1', false);
INSERT INTO test (value, flag) VALUES ('1', false);
```

I have tried playing with `EXCLUDE` constraint but was unable to make it work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for a unique [partial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html) index:

```
create unique index no_false_duplicates on test (value, flag) where not flag
```

You'll have to figure out what you want to do about `null` values in `flag` of course. I'd recommend making the `flag` column `not null` since `null` booleans are rarely what you want.

See the [CREATE INDEX documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html) for details.